# How do I use Mocha/Chai to start checking for DOM elements after a JavaScript Object create it?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

Would I need to use a `setTimeout`? (And it works when I do).  The problem I'm having is that the `FeedObject` does an asynchronous call, so when a new instance of it is created, it takes sometime before it can inject itself to the DOM.

```
describe('Default Case', function () {
            before(function () {
                $divHolder = $('#divHolder');
                $divHolder.html('');
                var myComponent = new FeedObject({
                    div: $divHolder[0],
                    prop: {
                        id: 'myFeed',
                    },
                    client: {}
                });

                myComponent.createDOMElements();
            });
            it('should exist', function () {
                console.log($divHolder.find('.feed-item')); // This does not exist unless I use a timeout
            });
```

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, the `new FeedObject` does an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to determine when `new FeedObject` is done. Depending on what `FeedObject` provides, it could mean:

- Providing a callback that it called when `new FeedObject` is done. Call `done` in the callback.
- Listening to an event (most likely a custom jQuery event). Call `done` in the event handler.
- Make the `before` hook return a promise that exists on the object returned by `new FeedObject`. For instance, the `ready` field could contain this promise, and you'd do `return myComponent.ready`. Mocha will wait for the promise to be resolved. (Remove the `done` argument from your `before` hook.)

I strongly suggest that you add one of the facilities above rather than use `setTimeout`. The problem with `setTimeout` is that it is always suboptimal: either you wait longer than you need for the DOM to be ready, or you set a timeout which is super close to the real time it take to be ready but in some cases the timeout will be too short (e.g. if your machine happens to have a spike of activity that does not leave enough CPU for the browser running the test code) and the test will fail for bogus reasons.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `new FeedObject` makes an AJAX call. I just need for the `FeedObject` to finish and then be insterted into the DOM before any of the test cases gets executed.

Comment: Yeah, use `expect(callbackCalled).to.be.true;`.

Answer (score 0):

Well `setTimeOut` will work (until the server response takes longer than the time you specified and then it won’t work) but it’s definitely not the best or fastest way to do it. When you’re using an async call, you need to define a callback method that runs *after* the code is finished. The idea of the code should be something like this:

```
describe('Default Case', function () {
  // Your code goes here

  $.ajax = function(ajaxOpts)
  {
    var doneCallback = ajaxOpts.done;
    doneCallback(simulatedAjaxResponse);
  };

  function fetchCallback(user)
  {
    expect(user.fullName).to.equal("Tomas Jakobsen");
    done();
  };

  fetchCurrentUser(fetchCallback);
});
```

If you need even more details you could check this very helpful [link](http://martinfowler.com/articles/asyncJS.html). Hope that helps!

Comment: If there a way to detect if the callback succeeded or not?

Comment: @Y2H, The only thing I need to run once the `FeedObject` finishes its AJAX call is the test cases. Do I just set the callback to be the test cases?

Comment: @ayjay Exactly. That’s its main purpose in Chai actually.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this [async chai plugin](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/). If you are using a promise api (probably the most [straight-forward](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) way to handle async testing), this makes testing async ops very simple. You just have to remember to `return` any invocation that is async (or returns a promise) so chai knows to 'wait' before continuing.

```js
describe(() => {
  let sut
  beforeEach(() => {
    sut = new FeedObject()
    return sut.createDomElements() // <- a promise
  })
  it('should exist', () => {
    $('#target').find('.feed-item').should.exist
  })
})
```

Also consider the goals of this testing: why are you doing it? I find that a lot of DOM insert/remove/exists testing is wasted effort. This is particularly true if you are testing a 3rd party library/framework as part of your application code. The burden of proof is on the library/framework to prove it is correct (and most well-written libraries already have a testing suite), not your app. If you are concerned about testing 'did I correctly invoke this 3rd party code' there are better ways to do that without touching the DOM.